# Verilog : Large Bus OR synthesis

Tags: verilog

I'm looking to do a logical OR of a bus.

The working code:

```
parameter Width = 8;
wire my_bus [Width-1:0];
wire bus_or = (my_bus[0] || my_bus[1] || ... || my_bus[Width-1])
```

That works fine but is entirely unsuitable for large busses (i.e. 64 bit)

I have seen: (from [here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/VerilogTips.html))

```
wire bus_or = |my_bus;
```

However this just complains with the error: Illegal operand of unary operator '|' and Illegal right hand side of continuous assign.

Interestingly the syntax:

```
wire bus_or = |{my_bus[0], my_bus[1], ..., my_bus[Width-1]}
```

Works fine, despite the concatenation creating a bus, with the original un-split object being a bus to start with...

We are using generate blocks to create various signals, wires, registers etc with the aim of extensible parameterised code. It seems a shame if syntax for a bus OR is so error prone.

What i'd love is something as simple as wire bus_or = |my_bus;

Sorry.
Very simple answer!!!

The `wire bus_or = |my_bus;` notation works fine when the bus is declared as a vector BUT NOT when its an array: see [here](http://www.verilogtutorial.info/chapter_3.htm).

Answer (score 5):

You are not defining a N bit bus but a collection of 1 bit busses.

You really want :

```
parameter Width = 8;
wire [Width-1:0] my_bus ;
```

That should allow the following to work.

```
wire bus_or = |my_bus;
```

NB: it is good practise to make constants upper case. WIDTH instead of Width. May be add some semantics to it as well, W_DATA or W_CONTROL etc.

Answer (score 0):

Morgan has replied correctly, you have to define your bus in packed array format to perform an operation on entire bus.

data_type [width-1:0] bus.
In memory it will be stored as
 |x|bus_width-1|.....|bus_1|bus_0|

Unpacked array is used to perform bitwise operation
data_type bus [width-1:0]
in memory is will be stored as
|x|x|bus_0|
|x|x|bus_1|
|x|x|bus_1|
.
.
.
|x|x|bus_width-1|